# Simple adjective for "of the size of a proper class"?

Tags: set-theory, terminology

It's just a wording question:

> How does one tell - by a simple
>   adjective - that a collection is "of
>   the size of a **proper** class"?

Their might be several sizes of proper classes, but on the other side, it's not a problem that there are several sizes of infinite/uncountable classes to call all of them "infinite/uncountable".

The context is: How do I have to proceed with "there are *finitely* many, *infinitely* many, *countably* many, *uncountably* many, *weakly inaccessibly* many, *strongly inaccessibly* many, ..." (see [Inaccessible Cardinals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inaccessible_cardinal))?

Comment: @Harry: Thanks for renaming the tag. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: To be honest: I cannot see why this question should be closed. Is it trivial, "not a real question", subjective,... whatever? I, personally, see it as a problem that one cannot talk of collections being "of the size of a proper class" by a single, simple adjective - may it be composed like "weakly/strongly inaccessible" or not.

Comment: Of the answers given so far, "proper-class-many" wins for being completely unambiguous, although it's not as simple as some of the others. But what I fail to see now is why any of this is an issue. Just say something at the outset of the paper or talk, as in my edited answer. 

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Proper-class-many**.

> “We show that if there exist proper class many Woodin cardinals, then the set of reals x for which there is exists an ordinal α with {a ∈ Pω1 (α) | x ∈ L[a]} stationary is countable.”     —Paul Larson, *Reals constructible from many countable sets of
>   ordinals*.

It’s grammatically ugly, but mathematically transparent and unambiguous, and rolls off the tongue reasonably well.  I’ve heard it used by and among set theorists, category theorists, and homotopy theorists, without confusion — I’m pretty sure it’s as widely understood as anything will be for this distinction.

Comment: In that quote, the author could just say "arbitrarily large Woodin cardinals". Every set of cardinals is bounded, so any unbounded class of cardinals is a proper class. 

Comment: +1, I was just typing that as an answer and was going to reference Larson as well.  Also do a Google search for: "proper class many" cardinals. 

Comment: @Carl Mummert: that’s true — but similarly, Euclid could have said “there are arbitrarily large prime numbers”.  In each case, there’s a slight difference in connotations; I can see why Larson might have considered both options and chosen what he did.  [Oblig. note: IANAHOM; I do not know how Euclid actually worded that theorem.]

Answer (score 5):

The word that immediately comes to mind is "[large](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/large+category)". "Large category", etc.

**Edit:** Carl Mummert suggested this one, which I should have remembered myself and which is definitely widely used: "unbounded". "Unboundedly many Woodin cardinals", "unbounded rank", etc.

It seems to me that the simplest solution would be to say at the outset something like, "for us, 'large' will mean 'proper-class-many'..." or something similar.

Comment: I tend to think of "large" as a relative term.  For instance, if $\kappa$ is an uncountable regular cardinal, it makes sense to talk about things that are $\kappa$-small and $\kappa$-large with somewhat of a straight face.

Comment: Sounds good, too, but it's too much "insider parlance": for the non-insider even "countably many" is "large".

Comment: Guys: this terminology is *quite* standard. If someone emphasizes that a category is large, you can be *quite* sure that he means the class of morphisms is a proper class. This answers Hans's question. 

Comment: @Todd: I do agree that this terminology is standard among category theorists. But I am looking for terms that are understood among general mathematicians.

Comment: Hans, when I said this is *quite* standard, I meant it. The usage is not restricted to category theorists: I am sure the usage is widely understood among general mathematicians who have reason to care about set-class distinctions (homotopy theorists, algebraic geometers, etc.). If you want to debate this, then show me evidence that the term is liable to be misunderstood by those who care about set-class distinctions. Why are you asking this question, anyway? 

Comment: @Hans, if you want to be understood among general mathematicians, define the term.

Comment: Unfortunately, "large" also has another meaning, in the context "large cardinal."   

Comment: @Todd: I’ve often heard it used as Harry describes — eg someone will fix a Grothendieck universe, and use “small” to mean “of a size contained in that universe”, and “large” for other sets.  Admittedly, four times out of five this is just because they were brought up with a third-hand presentation of ZFC and believe it’s unhygienic to ever mention something that’s not a set, when actually their “large” things could perfectly reasonably be proper classes after all…  but nonetheless, it is often used to mean that, and sometimes advisedly so.

Comment: @Andreas: sure. The word "regular" also has more than one meaning. But generally people pick up which meaning is meant from context. @Peter: okay, that's true. But if the speaker *hadn't* mentioned such set-theoretic assumptions which would thus qualify the meaning of "large", the audience would no doubt interpret his "large collection" as referring to a proper class, and if that's not what the speaker meant, it would be his fault for not mentioning his assumptions. 

Answer (score 4):

I've heard the term "absolutely infinite" used to describe classes of size $\Omega$, the class of all ordinals.

Comment: Sounds good: "absolutely infinite" - there seems nothing to be beyond.

Comment: But the class of all ordinals might be strictly smaller than the class of all sets...

Comment: @Francois: You name it: *might* be, but doesn't *have to* be (so far as I have understood).

Comment: @François: I realize that things get kinda murky at this point, but at least up to "essential size", the skeleton of $\Omega$ has more objects than the skeleton of $Set$.

Comment: @Harry: Please help me to understand: The class $\Omega$ of all ordinals might be "larger" than the class of all sets? (You talk about *skeletons*, so what is the skeleton of a class?) (And what is "essential size"?)

Comment: @Hans The size of 'the' skeleton of a collection of sets/ordinals is the size of the collection of isomorphism classes of set/ordinals (i.e. one element per isomorphism class in the category of such). For instance, $\omega$ has underlying set isomorphic to any other countable ordinal, but they are not isomorphic as ordinals. I gather Harry is hinting at reasoning along these lines.

Comment: @David: Thanks for the hints (definitely!). But as Harry just stated: "things get kinda murky at this point".

Comment: I think "absolutely infinite" was already used by Cantor to indicate the size of inconsistent totalities (which correspond pretty well to the newer concept of proper classes).

Answer (score 2):

I nominate "too big".

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.03.08